# What happens to existing connections to a server after it has been marked as backup in nginx

Tags: nginx

After modifying the nginx up configuration to mark a server as a backup from this :

```
upstream backend {    
    server backup1.example.com:8080;
    server backup2.example.com:8080;
}
```

to this

```
upstream backend {    
    server backup1.example.com:8080;
    server backup2.example.com:8080   backup;
}
```

what happens to existing connections on backup2.example.com:8080? will they immediately be routed to backup1.example.com or will they persist on backup2.example.com until the connection is disconnected?